# Using oracle bind variables with select_all in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to take advantage of bind variables in Ruby on Rails, and it doesn't need to instantiate a model, so I'm using select_all like so

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  'select * from users where id = :test', 
  {test: 'foo'}
)
```

But I get this big old error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound: select * from users where id = :test
    from stmt.c:243:in oci8lib_220.so
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.4.1/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:127:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3.61/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:149:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3.61/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:696:in `block in exec_query'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3.61/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1505:in `log'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3.61/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:676:in `exec_query'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3.61/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1457:in `select'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
```

Digging into the ActiveRecord code, it seems to be going to this method:

```
def select_all(arel, name = nil, binds = [])
  select(to_sql(arel, binds), name, binds)
end
```

This suggests that my `binds` hash is going to the `name` argument, but this puzzles me further:

- What is expected in the `name` argument?
- It looks like `binds` is expected to be an array.

How can I use this method to take advantage of Oracle's bind variables?

---

**Edit:** It was suggested that I set the `name` to `nil` and express my binds as an array of arrays:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  'select * from users where id = :test', 
  nil, 
  {test: 'foo'}.to_a
)
```

I see this error in return

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :test:Symbol
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for :test:Symbol: select * from users where id = :test
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax might a bit weird, I guess the `name` is an explicit name for the prepared statement, which you can leave nil. The array is a bit weird as well, but it allows for "unnamed" bind variables.

So your statement should look as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  'select * from users where id = :test', 
  nil, 
  {test: 'foo'}.to_a
)
```

Alternatively, since you are using oracle, you could also directly use the `ruby-oci8` gem (instead of the general activerecord wrapper): see the [bind_param documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8%2FCursor%3Abind_param)
where `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection` is a ruby-oci8 connection. Not really sure if I would advise to do this, but I wanted to be complete, and in some cases it helps if you can use some features directly.

Comment: On which rails version are you? I see it recently got a bit more complicated: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27923

Comment: From the rails test-case I do not immediately see named bind parameters?? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/127509c071b4f983f2beafc8766e990670a21215/activerecord/test/cases/bind_parameter_test.rb#L42 So if you really need that use ruby-oci8 directly?

Comment: Rails 3.2.2 at the moment (my company is a little behind(“)